# Visual studio path configuration on Windows for LEAN theorem prover

Tags: visual-studio-code, lean

I am trying to set up my VS Code environment to work with LEAN the automated theorem prover.

I set up a new project following the tutorial at [here](https://leanprover-community.github.io/install/project.html) and have a file called `test.lean`, given as follows:

```
import data.real.basic
```

I get the following error:

```
invalid import: data.real.basic
could not resolve import: data.real.basic
```

The error message suggested I call `lean --path`, so I did, and obtained:

```
PS C:\Users\user\lean_test2> lean --path
{
  "is_user_leanpkg_path": false,
  "leanpkg_path_file": "C:\\Users\\user\\lean_test2\\leanpkg.path",
  "path": [
    "C:\\Users\\user\\.elan\\toolchains\\leanprover-community--lean---3.35.1\\bin\\..\\library",
    "C:\\Users\\user\\.elan\\toolchains\\leanprover-community--lean---3.35.1\\bin\\..\\lib\\lean\\library",
    "C:\\Users\\user\\lean_test2\\_target/deps/mathlib/src",
    "C:\\Users\\user\\lean_test2\\./src"
  ]
}
```

I noticed the paths use a mix of `/` and `\\`, but I don't think this will be a problem. I checked the third entry in the paths list, and found that the following file

```
C:\Users\user\lean_test2\_target\deps\mathlib\src\data\real\basic.lean
```

does indeed exist. So, what might be going wrong?

Comment: For those interested in Proof Assistants, there is a new proposed SE site [ProofAssistants](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants?referrer=Njg4YTJmMjYwOTIxNjdkNGEyMmZkNzE0Y2M4YmFhOTY3OWVmNDUwNWM3ZmFlMjYwYTRiYzZiZWY1ODg5ZjdiMqfBIyhShuHO9QbGuJfVwOYRvfVgPfbJQrn2UOFTeOe-0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the problem is, but you should usually either use the "open folder" feature in VScode to open the folder containing mathlib or open the folder containing a project depending on mathlib. There's also a `leanproject global-install` command you can use to globally install mathlib without having to open a folder in VScode, but I've never used this command myself.